# How to get correct HTML back from an Ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, format

I have made an Ajax call to a function which returns a whole html table.

```
     $.ajax({
    url: "/admin/project/getProjectTrackedTimes",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
      project_id : project,
      offset : offset,
      step : step,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.c-admin-timetrack-table').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
  })
}
```

Then in the php function I return the following:

```
return json_encode($block);
```

Now when I change something in the page with:

```
 $('.c-admin-timetrack-table').html(data);
```

This is the outcome: http://prntscr.com/l1rcer

The output is not in good html format.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Edit: I'm such a dumbass. Duplicated other code and changed some things for this function. Didn't delete the json_encode though, dumb. Thanks for the sharpness.

Comment: You're not returning HTML but JSON.

Comment: Try replacing this:
return json_encode($block);
by this:
echo $block;

Comment: Why did you use json_encode? it encodes it as json... json isn't html...

Answer (score -2):

try to replace this part

[before]

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.c-admin-timetrack-table').html(data);
},
```

[after]

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('.c-admin-timetrack-table').html(data);
},
```

evince to received data is json.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  In this case, it is better to fix the source problem (with an easy fix) than apply a patch (hence someone's downvote).  Please continue to contribute on another question.